# Graphics and sound issues in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 for development work and general usage. I plan to keep continue using windows for some other stuff. I have a HD 6950 (replacing it with something less antique and overpowered is on the list)  and I didn't know about the deprecation of fglrx, I have a few issues and I would like to know if I have any chance of solving them.

- I am unable to play any kind of video smoothly, audio and video cut out for 0.1 to 0.5 seconds, sometimes it has sync issues after that. This is system wide, even the speaker test had this issue once
- My video card fan is way louder than in Windows
- My PC uses about 30W more power in idle, I assume this is because my grapics card doesn't properly do power management, is there any way to solve or check this? The only think I have found is rovclock, but it outputs garbage and exits with a floating point exception.

Where do I start?

Comment: I think you might have hit the nail on the head when you said "I didn't know about the deprecation of fglrx". I am an Intel and Nvidia fanboy (so not an expert with AMD) but I think that fglrx drivers have been removed as they are no longer supported and Ubuntu has moved over to the open source driver stack for these devices. I guess you have no option but to wait for the new open source drivers to work and/or install an NVIDIA card for the time being.

Comment: If your computer also has Intel HD Graphics, you could disable the dedicated GPU while using Ubuntu

Comment: @AndroidDev I have a 2600k, so technically I could do that. But that generation isn't known for it's good graphics. The other issue is that I am using 2 screens (3 if I could the TV), and changing Bios settings and physically changing connections all the time isn't really a solution.

Comment: @hatterman As far as I understand the new open source drivers are here but my card is to old for them. But I am really not asking for much, just the ability to play youtube video's. I can't imagine that even that is to much to ask.

Comment: @eew - GPU drivers on Linux are just awful, unfortunately.  Let me put it to you this way: using the proprietary Nvidia driver on my GPU, I can play a 1080p@60 youtube video just fine, but if I simply drag a window in front of the area where the video is playing, everything starts lagging... and yet it is smooth as silk doing the same thing on Win7.